# Count occurence of specific code per customer in 6 month period

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that contains the following:

```
customerid | date (dmy) | productid

   John    |    1-3-14    |     A
   John    |    7-5-14    |     Y
   John    |    8-5-14    |     Y
   John    |    1-10-15   |     B
   John    |    1-11-15   |     Y
   Pete    |    1-7-15    |     Y
```

I need to find out how often customer X has bought Product Y in a six-month period.

The start of a period is defined as the first time a customer has bought one of the products A,B, C or Y. The endtime of a period is exactly six months after that.

The next period starts when the customer buys again one of the products A,B,C or Y.

So the output should be

```
customerid | period-start | period-end | countofY
   John    |    1-3-14    |   8-5-14   |    2
   John    |    1-10-15   |   1-11-15  |    1
   Pete    |    1-7-15    |   1-7-15   |    1
```

Comment: Your sample results do not match your requirements.  John bought 3 Y's in total.  The first start date of which was 7/5 so why is period start 1/3? and wouldn't period end 1 sec less than be period start + 6 months and next period start be min(period start)+6 months?

Comment: John bought product A on 1-3-14 so that is when the first 6 month period starts. That period lasts until 1-9-14 (+6 months) and the last date to fall in that period is 8-5-14. In that period he bought product Y twice.

Comment: my fault DMY not MDY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.Customerid, MIN(c.pdate) AS startperiod, c1.endperiod, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(temp.productid) FROM Customer temp 
    WHERE temp.Customerid = c.Customerid
    AND temp.pdate >= MIN(c.pdate)
    AND temp.pdate <= c1.endperiod 
    GROUP BY temp.productid HAVING temp.productid ='Y'
)AS countOfY 
FROM Customer c 
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 c1.pdate AS endperiod  
    FROM Customer c1 
    WHERE c1.Customerid = c.Customerid
    AND c1.pdate >= c.pdate
    AND 
    (
        DATEDIFF(MONTH, c.pdate, c1.pdate) < 6  
        OR 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 t.pdate FROM Customer t
            WHERE t.Customerid = c.Customerid
            AND t.pdate < c1.pdate
        ) IS NULL       
    )   
    ORDER BY c1.pdate DESC
)AS c1 GROUP BY c1.endperiod, c.Customerid
```

Comment: We need to find optimized way of producing result.
But The above query will give you desirable answer as per my knowledge.
We can use cursor too to get desirable answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE_DateRanges AS (
    SELECT
        customerid,
        productid,
        MIN(purchase_date) AS period_start,
        DATEADD(MM, 6, MIN(purchase_date)) AS period_end
    FROM
        My_Table
    GROUP BY
        customerid,
        productid
)
SELECT
    DR.customerid,
    DR.productid,
    DR.period_start,
    DR.period_end,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    CTE_DateRanges DR
INNER JOIN My_Table MT ON
    MT.customerid = DR.customerid AND
    MT.productid = DR.productid AND
    MT.purchase_date BETWEEN DR.period_start AND DR.period_end
GROUP BY
    DR.customerid,
    DR.productid,
    DR.period_start,
    DR.period_end,
```